# mysql: updating/adding to a column in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
calls DATE(DATE) GENDER(VARCHAR(1)) NAME(VARCHAR(100))
```

I want to do this :

```
UPDATE calls WHERE GENDER="M" SET NAME = CONCAT("sir: ",NAME) ;
UPDATE calls WHERE GENDER="F" SET NAME = CONCAT("mrs: ",NAME) ;
```

but it is not working, How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE calls SET NAME = CONCAT("sir: ",NAME) WHERE GENDER="M"  ;
```

> **use set name before the where clause**

Answer (score 2):

You can even do this in a single statement for both cases

```
update calls set name = case 
    when gender = 'f' then concat('mrs: ', name)
    when gender = 'm' then concat('mr: ', name)
    else name
  end;
```

See this fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q2FtjGusyjdL2xPJuGtSJK/3

Comment: Thanks, so the lesson is where is always on last position. and case/when :))

Comment: Do not run it twice.